# Can not share URL's on Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, dotnetnuke

This functionality was working fine a couple of days ago, however since yesterday I cannot seem to add anymore of my Blog's URL's to my Facebook page.

This is the URL I am trying to to share on my Facebook page:
http://www.summerfestivalguide.co.uk/Festival_News/EntryId/1303/The-Rolling-Stones-Arctic-Monkeys-Mumford-Sons-to-headline-Glastonbury.aspx

Can you see anything fundamentally wrong with this URL and any idea why FB wont pick it up.

I also tried this in the Facebook Debugger but it seems to timeout.

My website is built in DotNetNuke and is using the DNN Blog module.

Comment: Are you still having the issue? I don't seem to have a problem loading that URL into FB

Comment: Hey Chris, I actually spent all of Easter weekend migrating the DotNetNuke Blog module to the Ventrian News Article Module.  It all seems to work again now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up migrating the DNN Blog module to the Ventrian News Article Module which is a much better Blogging module in my opinion.  After the migration, every thing seems to be working now.

Comment: The blog module is currently undergoing a massive rewrite (I found that out today) but I don't know when it would be available

Comment: Hey Chris, DNN really messed up with DNN Blog v5.0, it made it impossible to migrate to it from the older blog module version as it didn't migrate over categories or tags (if I can remember correctly).  Having around 1200 Blog entries to manually update was not feasible so the only route that made sense was to migrate over to Ventrian News Articles and using URL Master to help with the URL rewriting.  I do hope that the next release of the blog module is a huge step up from the current one.